# Which username and password should I use for Amazon Keyspaces (managed Cassandra)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cassandra, amazon-iam, amazon-keyspaces

I am unable to connect to AWS Keyspaces using .NET Core due to an authentication error:

> AuthenticationException 'Provided username nick and/or password are incorrect')

I am not sure what values I should give to `PlainTextAuthProvider`.

I have tried using:

- My AWS Console credentials
- AWS access key / secret key pair

**How do I generate credentials for AWS Keyspaces?**

---

My code, in case it is relevant:

```ml
open System
open Cassandra

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
  async {    
    let cluster =
      Cluster.Builder()
        .AddContactPoints("cassandra.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com")
        .WithPort(9142)
        .WithAuthProvider(PlainTextAuthProvider ("username", "password123"))
        .WithSSL()
        .Build()

    use! session =
      cluster.ConnectAsync ()
      |> Async.AwaitTask

    ()
  }
  |> Async.RunSynchronously

  0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The option is found in the *IAM section*.

Naviagate to:

- "Services" drop-down
- Click "Identity and Access Management (IAM)"
- Open the "Users" tab
- Click on *You username*
- Open the "Security credentials" tab
- Scroll to the "Credentials for Amazon Keyspaces" section
- Click "Generate Credentials"

[image]

This will show a pop-up where you can generate credentials.

---

Additionally, the code should specify a Keyspace:

```ml
open System
open Cassandra

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
  async {    
    let cluster =
      Cluster.Builder()
        .AddContactPoints("cassandra.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com")
        .WithPort(9142)
        .WithAuthProvider(PlainTextAuthProvider ("username", "password123"))
        .WithSSL()
        .Build()

    use! session =
      cluster.ConnectAsync "test_keyspace"
      |> Async.AwaitTask

    ()
  }
  |> Async.RunSynchronously

  0
```